# SQL Join tables with empty values

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

Lets say Table1 and Table2

They both have one shared value(id)

What I'm looking for is whether there is any function to combine them both based on that key, however if table2 has more elements, i want columns of table1 to be empty, and if table1 has more elements, table 2 columns to be empty

I tried a lot of different joins, but most of the time I end up with a lot of duplicate values as it tries to fill in both sides.

Tried Full outer join, Full join, etc

[image: Something like this]

Comment: What you're looking for is probably `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN`. That picture explains very well: http://i.imgur.com/1m55Wqo.jpg

Comment: @Flo: https://blog.jooq.org/2016/07/05/say-no-to-venn-diagrams-when-explaining-joins/

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `full join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t1 full join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: I End up with several duplicates, It dupes as many t1 entries as there are t2 entries

Answer (score 0):

The above code from Gordon is right. However, since you have not specified the database and its version, I will post an alternate version for MySQL, which should also work for other databases.

Without duplicates:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table1
RIGHT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.id
```

With duplicates:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.id
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Table1
RIGHT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.id
```